# Renaming directories in bash using sed

Tags: bash, sed

i have several directories which i want to rename:
etc: 
"duedate-year" directory to "duedate" (just removing -year)
"start-year" directory to "start"

This is what i've tried:

```
for CACHE in `find ${DESTINATION_REPO} -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "*year" ` ;
do
set UPDATE="awk -F"-year" '{print $1}' $CACHE" ;
mv $CACHE  $UPDATE
done
```

However it doesn't succeed.  Is there away to rename directory using "sed" command?

Comment: You need to use backticks or `$(...)` to run a command and assign the output to a variable. You have the `awk` command in double quotes instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use a pipe. I do this:

```
for DIR in $(find ${DESTINATION_REPO} -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "*year"); do 
    mv "${DIR}" $(echo "${DIR}" | sed -E 's/year//')        
done
```

It should be noted that I am very much self taught and sometimes have bad habits...

After consulting gniourf_gniourf I am posting a more robust version ([read more](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)) which is a "code lift" of Ed Morton's answer below.

```
find ${DESTINATION_REPO} -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "*-year"|
while IFS= read -r DIR  
do 
    mv "${DIR}" $(echo "${DIR}" | sed -E 's/year//')        
done
```

Comment: Mr. Jobs apparently autocorrected "regex" to "reggae", but it is a fun autocorrect so I will leave it.

Comment: Lots of bad habits here, indeed: `for DIR in $(find ...)` is very bad: it breaks when there are filenames containing spaces or glob characters; you need to quote all your variables too, for the same reason. It's funny that you're using the highly useless curlies around your variable names, but refuse to use the highly mandatory quotes. Go figure.

Comment: The main problem is `for DIR in $(find ...)`, so the whole design must be rethought. Ed Morton's solution is one of the most robust (the most robust is the one I gave in a comment of his post `:D`).

Comment: Thank you for the constructive points. I will add reference to his post since mine is "accepted".

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning the result of `awk` incorrectly. It should be inside backticks or `$(...)`. And to process a variable, you need to pipe `echo $CACHE` to it, not use `$CACHE` as the filename argument (that will process the *contents* of the file). So that line should be:

And variables aren't assigned using `set`, you just write `var=value`.

So that line should be:

```
UPDATE=$(echo "$CACHE" | awk -F-year '{print $1}`)
```

But there's no need to use `awk` for this at all, you can use shell variable expansion operators:

```
UPDATE=${CACHE%%-year*}
```

`%%year*` means to remove the longest trailing part of the value that matches the wildcard `-year*`.

Answer (score 2):

Many shell solutions will "work" for a given sample input set and then blow up disastrously later, usually due to unquoted variables, incorrect processing of blanks, etc. This should be safe unless your file name contains newlines (in which case see `find -print0` and `xargs -0`):

```
find "$DESTINATION_REPO" -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "*-year" |
while IFS= read -r CACHE
do
    mv -- "$CACHE" "${CACHE%-year}"
done
```

Comment: And this one blows up for filename containing newlines (this is very unlikely, I know, but it's still possible). Two ways to fix this: use `print0` and `read` with the null byte delimiter or: `find "$DESTINATION_REPO" -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "*-year" -exec bash -c 'for CACHE; do mv -- "$CACHE" "${CACHE/-year}"; done' _ {} +`

Answer (score 1):

Or use the `rename` command

```
rename 's/-year//' *year
```